# Error while trying to connect ms access db with angular framework (nodejs have been used)

Tags: node.js, angular, ms-access, adodb

Hi I am trying to connect Microsoft Access DB with angular framework. I am using following code to do that.

```
insertData()

{  

'use strict';

    // Get the adodb module

   //var require: any;

    const ADODB = require("node-adodb");
    ADODB.debug = true;
// Connect to the MS Access DB
    var connection = ADODB.open('Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\\Automation\\student.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;');

// Query the DB
    connection
      .execute('INSERT INTO student(SNO, NAME, AGE) VALUES (210001, "Rahul", "10")')
      .then(data => {
        console.log(data);
      })

  }
```

When executing above piece of code, I am getting below error in Command Line

> ERROR in ./node_modules/node-adodb/lib/proxy.js Module not found:
>   Error: Can't resolve 'child_process' in
>   'C:\Users\Documents\Tuitorial\Exercise\selenium-automation-builder\node_modules\node-adodb\lib'
>   resolve 'child_process' in
>   'C:\Users\Documents\Tuitorial\Exercise\selenium-automation-builder\node_modules\node-adodb\lib'
>   Parsed request is a module   using description file:
>   C:\Users\Documents\Tuitorial\Exercise\selenium-automation-builder\node_modules\node-adodb\package.json
>   (relative path: ./lib)
>       Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration   after using description file:
>   C:\Users\Documents\Tuitorial\Exercise\selenium-automation-builder\node_modules\node-adodb\package.json
>   (relative path: ./lib)
>       resolve as module
>         C:\Users\Documents\Tuitorial\Exercise\selenium-automation-builder\node_modules\node-adodb\lib\node_modules
>   doesn't exist or is not a directory
>         C:\Users\Documents\Tuitorial\Exercise\selenium-automation-builder\node_modules\node_modules
>   doesn't exist or is not a directory
>         C:\Users\Documents\Tuitorial\Exercise\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
>         C:\Users\Documents\Tuitorial\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
>         C:\Users\Documents\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
>         C:\Users\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
>         C:\Users\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
>         C:\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
>         looking for modules in C:\Users\Documents\Tuitorial\Exercise\selenium-automation-builder\node_modules\node-adodb\node_modules
>           using description file: C:\Users\Documents\Tuitorial\Exercise\selenium-automation-builder\node_modules\node-adodb\package.json
>   (relative path: ./node_modules)
>             Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
>           after using description file: C:\Users\Documents\Tuitorial\Exercise\selenium-automation-builder\node_modules\node-adodb\package.json
>   (relative path: ./node_modules)
>             using description file: C:\Users\Documents\Tuitorial\Exercise\selenium-automation-builder\node_modules\node-adodb\package.json
>   (relative path: ./node_modules/child_process)
>               no extension
>                 Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
>                 C:\Users\Documents\Tuitorial\Exercise\selenium-automation-builder\node_modules\node-adodb\node_modules\child_process doesn't exist
>               .ts
>                 Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
>                 C:\Users\Documents\Tuitorial\Exercise\selenium-automation-builder\node_modules\node-adodb\node_modules\child_process.ts
>   doesn't exist
>               .js.........................